Should I use reverse proxy or 301 redirection in nginx
I have my main public site running as (https://example.com) on nginx. When (https://example.com/shift) is visited, I should have the content of (https://newDomain.com/shift). I can do this with 301 or reverse proxy. Which one should I do and why? both the sites are publically accessible. The example.com is hosted on nginx while newDomain.com is on AWS cloudfront.
With reverse proxy, my browser will be on the exmapl.com URL while on 301, I will be shifted to newDomain.com.
Thanks

Placing an nginx reverse proxy in front of CloudFront would entirely negate any benefits of CloudFront, and also place unnecessary load on your nginx server.

Yes, but there are the requirements to serve the content of new domain on my site without making the browser url be changed.

Then CloudFront should serve the domain, and everything should go through CloudFront. Configure CloudFront with multiple origins (your nginx server, and S3)

And also, if a 301 redirect to a new domain is an unacceptable solution for you, that is key information that should be included in the question.

Is there any way to use reverse proxy between two servers and the main url should not be changed?

Each approach has its merits, Choose a 301 redirect for simplicity and SEO benefits if you want to redirect users permanently.
Opt for a reverse proxy if you need a seamless user experience without changing the URL. But, placing Nginx in front of CloudFront doesn't make any sense. also, it will make an unnecessary load on your Nginx server.
so consider your specific requirements before making a decision.
For 301 redirect you can add the following directive:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /shift {
        return 301 https://newDomain.com/shift;
    }
} 


Thank you for the helpful answer. My requirements are I don't want the browser url to be changed. I tried reverse proxy but the js and css files were not loaded. How to achieve this?
